# Scala: Type declaration on Literal

Tags: scala

In slick "dynamic filter" example I've encountered the syntax which haven't seen before in Scala:

**true: Rep[Boolean]**

```
val q4 = coffees.filter { coffee =>
  List(
      criteriaColombian.map(coffee.name === _),
      criteriaEspresso.map(coffee.name === _),
      criteriaRoast.map(coffee.name === _) // not a condition as `criteriaRoast` evaluates to `None`
  ).collect({case Some(criteria)  => criteria}).reduceLeftOption(_ || _).getOrElse(true: Rep[Boolean])
}
```

So I've tried in repl something like: `1: Int`, `"s": String`

What is it used for? To explicitly specify the type of literal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This here:

```
(expression : Type)
```

is called a *type ascription*. It is used to either ensure that your assumptions about the type of certain expressions in your code is correct, or to help the compiler with the type inference.

There is a third use of that: to enforce implicit conversion to the specified type.

I'm not a specialist when it comes to coffee, but the only plausible explanation for it is:

- There is a type constructor `Rep[X]` somewhere in scope
- In the implicit scope, there is an implicit conversion with signature

-

```
implicit def booleanIsRep(b: Boolean): Rep[Boolean] = ...
```

or, alternatively:

- In the implicit scope there is a polymorphic conversion with signature

-

```
implicit def everythingCanWrapToRep[X](x: X): Rep[X] = ...
```

You might try to add compiler option `-print` to see where implicit conversions are inserted.